# ARM Processor board and Programming

Tags: arm

I am trying to develop an ARM development board using ATSAM3U4C with a 96 MHz clock, a few LEDs and a button for external interrupt. Shown below is a little circuit that I have put in place. Using Atmel SAM-ICE 20 pin JTAG connector as the debugger and using Atmel Studio 6.0 for programming. For JTAG connection, pin 3 on 20 pin socket connects to NRST and pin 15 connects to NRSTB.

So far I got the LEDs to blink but I have a few questions:

1. The debugger does not seem to erase the chip when loading the program. I can run the program once but then to run the program again, I have to use one of the buttons to drive the Erase Pin high (using U5 for now).
2. I noticed that my 96 MHz crystal oscillator is not actually being used by the ARM processor. Have I wired it incorrectly?

These are the only two issues I am facing right now. I have been using 8-bit microcontrollers and thought this would be a good learning to design my own board and learn to program on it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the ATSAM's, but I know the STM32F4's (as a comparative ARM Cortex-M) wouldn't work with an external 96MHz source - their working range is 4 to 26MHz.

I'd try a slower crystal or oscillator and use the PLL (assuming the ATSAM has one) to increase the system clock to 96MHz.

Re your problems with odd behaviour following an erase/program cycle, maybe try a different toolset.  The [Coocox](http://www.coocox.org) IDE (at v.1.7.7) appears to support your MCU (AT91SAM3U4C?), although I'm less sure that it supports the SAM-ICE.  If it doesn't then you can buy a [CoLinkEx debugger](http://www1.coocox.org/CoLinkExGuide/Buy_CoLinkEx.htm) that is definitely supported and should work with almost any Cortex-M for around US$20.

*Disclaimer: I have no relationship with Coocox, I just think they have an awesome free product.*

I suggest this because I've encountered a situation in the past where if I used vendor A's tools then I had to power cycle between erase/program cycles; but if I used vendor B's tools then I didn't, despite flashing exactly the same binary.

Comment: On Page 457 of datasheet under Clock Generator, it says 'A 96 to 192 MHz programmable PLL (input from 8 to 16 MHz), capable of providing the clock MCK to the processor and to the peripherals.' What does this mean exactly? How can a 16 MHz clock help generate 96 MHz?

Comment: The input crystal is up to 16MHz. The internal PLL is able to multiply this frequency up to 192MHz.

Comment: @EugeneSh., Thanks. Why cant 8 bit microcontrollers do this? It will make things a whole lot easier.

Comment: @DavidNorman 8-bit MCU's don't do this because they're toys in comparison to any Cortex-M.

Comment: @markt, can you suggest something about the chip erase problem. I have no clue why this is happening. After loading the program once I have to manually pull the Erase pin high to program it again.

Comment: @DavidNorman that one I can't help you with; I've never used an ATSAM.  The only ARM I've used a lot is the STM32F4, which has no equivalent pin. You issue an Erase command to it via JTAG.

Comment: @markt, JTAG should be erasing the chip by default before uploading the program. But still I erased the .elf file that it uses to program the flash but that still did not work. What works is to drive the ERASE pin high for more than 100mS.

Comment: Your controller may have an option to bypass inner oscillator, at least LPC's have such. That wqy your crystal oscillator could be usable

Comment: @DavidNorman updated my answer with a suggestion.

Comment: @markt, ATSAM3u4c is supported by Atmel's SAM-ICE debugger on Atmel Studio 6.0. But I will definitely try out the debugger that you suggested and get back to you. Thanks for your help.